# Get everything after - and space, regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Input

```
ABC - MMM
```

Expected output

```
MMM
```

Everything after `-` and a `space`

Tried this `(-\s).+`

But I dont get rid of - and space.

https://regex101.com/r/0W7lhD/2

Comment: No need for regex: `"ABC - MMM".split(" - ")[1]`

Comment: @ctwheels *Get everything after - and space, **regex** javascript*

Comment: @Ele yep, why use regex though when there's a string function to do just that? K.I.S.S. :)

Comment: You're capturing the dash and the space by putting them in the parentheses. Put the parentheses on the thing you want to capture.

Comment: If you still want a regex after @ctwheels comment, capture the characters after the dash and space : `-\s(.+)`

Comment: @ctwheels the OP shows a sample, probably s/he needs to solve this using regex rather than split.

Comment: @Ele why though? If there's a better method. Why use a screwdriver to hit a nail into wood if you have a hammer?

Comment: @ctwheels Agree, however, you're assuming because the OP probably thought about the split and once again, s/he needs to solve this with regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there are multiple ways to go about this. The easiest and potentially best method is not to use regex at all.

**Method 1 - split**

Of course, you'd add a check to ensure that the element `[1]` exists, but this shows you the general idea of getting `MMM`.

```js
console.log("ABC - MMM".split(" - ")[1])
```

**Method 2 - regex group**

This method groups everything you *want* into capture group 1.

```js
console.log("ABC - MMM".match(/-\s(.+)/)[1])
```

**Method 3 - regex lookbehind**

This one was suggested by [Andrew Bone in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367964/3600709). While this works, it's currently only supported on Chrome 62+ (lookbehinds have little support in browsers at the moment). You can see the [RegExp Lookbehind Assertions proposal here as part of EMCA TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind).

```js
console.log("ABC - MMM".match(/(?<=-\s).+/)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `positive lookbehind` which means look for things after, but not including, a pattern. The syntax is `?<=`

```
(?<=-\s).+
```

Here is some [further reading](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Though this is the *correct* way to do this it's worth noting, as @ctwheels points out, support is currently very limited.

**EDIT:**

You can use split to turn the string into an array and then return the last string in the array.

This is a slightly long winded way to do it but I think it is more readable this way.

```js
var string = "ADSD - ASDASD";
var regex = /(-\s)/;

function matchAfter(string, pattern) {
  var short = string.split(pattern);
  return short[short.length - 1];
}

console.log(matchAfter(string, regex));
```

Comment: Only works in Chrome 62+ at the moment

Comment: looks like it is a bit of an overkill, even if it indeed gets you the full match without the dash and space

Comment: I need it to work in IE11

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the groups and get the last element from the array.

```js
console.log(("ABC - MMM".match(/-\s+(.+)/) || []).pop());
```